# Converting string to arraylist with special chars

Tags: android, encoding, arraylist

I have data in a string which I am converting to an arraylist, this works fine.

```
//get string from intent
String data= intent.getStringExtra("url").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

//convert to array list
arraylist =  new  ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(",")));
```

I have noticed this is failing however when the string contains any special characters, accents or umlauts for example.

I am assume this is down to the encoding ? How can I fix ??

Thanks

Comment: define `this is failing`

Comment: Logcat? The string is jarbled? what is the *ERROR*? Post Logcat if there is any exception and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like:

```
    String data = null;

    try {
        byte[] b = intent.getStringExtra("url").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").getBytes("UTF-8");
        data = new String(b, "UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    arraylist =  new  ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(",")));
```

hope it helps

Comment: so you are taking the utf-8 encoded bytes from the string and then recreating a string with those bytes, specifying they are utf-8 encoded. How do you expect this to do anything at all?